# Looking for a boto3 python example of injecting a aws pig step into an already running emr?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, apache-pig, emr

I'm looking for a good BOTO3 example of an AWS EMR already running and I wish to inject a Pig Step into that EMR.  Previously, I used the boto2.42 version of:

```
from boto.emr.connection import EmrConnection
from boto.emr.step import InstallPigStep, PigStep

#  AWS_ACCESS_KEY = '' # REQUIRED
#  AWS_SECRET_KEY = '' # REQUIRED
#  conn = EmrConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)

# loop next element on bucket_compare list 

pig_file = 's3://elasticmapreduce/samples/pig-apache/do-reports2.pig'
INPUT = 's3://elasticmapreduce/samples/pig-apache/input/access_log_1'
OUTPUT = '' # REQUIRED, S3 bucket for job output

pig_args = ['-p', 'INPUT=%s' % INPUT,
             '-p', 'OUTPUT=%s' % OUTPUT]
pig_step = PigStep('Process Reports', pig_file, pig_args=pig_args)
steps = [InstallPigStep(), pig_step]

conn.run_jobflow(name='prs-dev-test', steps=steps,
             hadoop_version='2.7.2-amzn-2', ami_version='latest',
             num_instances=2, keep_alive=False)
```

The main problem now is that, BOTO3 doesn't use: from `boto.emr.connection` import `EmrConnection`, nor from `boto.emr.step` import `InstallPigStep`, PigStep and I can't find an equivalent set of modules?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of checking, I've found a very simple way to inject Pig Script commands from within Python using the awscli and subprocess modules.  One can import awscli & subprocess, and then encapsulate and inject the desired PIG steps to an already running EMR with:

```
import awscli
import subprocess


cmd='aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-GU07FE0VTHNG --steps Type=PIG,Name="AggPigProgram",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[-f,s3://dev-end2end-test/pig_scripts/AggRuleBag.pig,-p,INPUT=s3://dev-end2end-test/input_location,-p,OUTPUT=s3://end2end-test/output_location]'

push=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
print(push.returncode)
```

Of course, you'll have to find your JobFlowID using something like:

```
aws emr list-clusters --active
```

Using the same subprocess and push command above.  Of course you can add monitoring to your hearts delight instead of just a print statement.

Comment: I have been finding a way to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add a new step to existing emr cluster job flow for a pig job sing **boto3**

**Note**: your script log file, input and output directories should have
the complete path in the format
`'s3://<bucket>/<directory>/<file_or_key>'`

```
emrcon = boto3.client("emr")    
cluster_id1 = cluster_status_file_content #Retrieved from S3, where it was recorded on creation
    
                step_id = emrcon.add_job_flow_steps(JobFlowId=str(cluster_id1),
                                                    Steps=[{
                                                            'Name': str(pig_job_name),
                                                            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
                                                            'HadoopJarStep': {
                                                                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                                                                'Args': ['pig', "-l", str(pig_log_file_full_path), "-f", str(pig_job_run_script_full_path), "-p", "INPUT=" + str(pig_input_dir_full_path), 
                                                                                        "-p", "OUTPUT=" + str(pig_output_dir_full_path) ]
                                                            }
                                                        }]
                                                    )
```

Please see screenshot to monitor-
[image]